# Can't change sys.ps1 in IDLE

Tags: python, prompt, python-idle, ps1

I've recently heard that you can change the prompt in python by changing variable `sys.ps1`. So I've decided to open IDLE, and write something like that:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.ps1 = ":::"
```

However, that created a new variable and nothing changed (prompt was still ">>>") - I rebooted IDLE and checked is this variable read by python... Nope:

```
>>> sys.ps1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    sys.ps1
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'ps1'
```

So, how do I change the prompt in python?
NOTE: The other functions/variables of *sys* module were read properly.

Comment: In 3.10.0b1, the prompt has been removed from the first line of interactive input to enable using 4-space indents instead of tabs that expand to 8 spaces. The first solution is a sidebar with fixed `>>>` and `...` prompts. A second solution, putting a prompt on a line by itself, may be in 3.10.0b2, possibly changeable with a dialog option rather than sys setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See issue #13657, ["IDLE doesn't recognize resetting sys.ps1"](https://bugs.python.org/issue13657), on the Python bug tracker. It was opened in 2011 and is still unresolved (as of this writing). So it is not possible to change the prompt from within IDLE's Python shell simply because IDLE does not support that.

Update (less than 24 hours later): The issue is now closed. In the upcoming version of IDLE, to be released with Python 3.10, prompts will be displayed differently. See comment by IDLE developer Terry Jan Reedy above. A setting to change the prompt may be added in the future.

In the current and earlier Python/IDLE releases, the prompt can be customized before starting IDLE, but not while running it. You'd need a little start-up script that does this:

```py
import sys
sys.ps1 = '::: '
import idlelib.idle
```

The reason you get that error message (`module 'sys' has no attribute 'ps1'`) is because the Python shell that IDLE presents to you is not actually in "interactive" mode. And only then is [`sys.ps1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.ps1) defined. You'd see the same error message if you tried to access `sys.ps1` in any other Python program that is directly executed. In this case, that Python program is IDLE itself.

Comment: I just closed #13657 https://bugs.python.org/issue13657 because of the Shell changes in 3.10.0b1 described in my comment above.  The snippet above should no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

The prompt strings specifying the primary and secondary prompt (their initial values in this case are `>>>`  and `...` ) of the interpreter are only defined if the interpreter is in **interactive** mode and [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) is more or less an integrated development environment for Python

Python interactive mode:
[image: Python interactive mode]

[sys.ps1 **doc**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.ps1)

Comment: You are correct that when Python runs the IDLE application from idlelib/idle.pyw or another idlelib file, Python is not in interactive mode but is rather in normal batch file mode.  It just happens that Python includes enough functions, including runtime `compile` to make it fairly easy to simulate interactive mode in most respects.